# Apple Magic Mouse causes crazy paging in date field

Tags: extjs

When I used my Apple Magic Mouse to select a date on a date field (either Ext JS 3.x or 4.x), it often starts scrolling months very rapidly and sort-of out of control. I think it might be due to the multi-touch sensitivity. It can happen even if I'm not trying to change the month but just select a date in current month. Is there a way to keep the mouse under control using javascript, or do I just need to learn how to use the mouse better?

Comment: Anything you did to "fix" the issue with that one device would likely degrade the experience for users of "regular" non-touch mice.

Comment: Thanks. I definitely do not want to degrade the experience for others. It's just peculiar that I don't recall having this UX issue using my Mac for anything else (html or native) except for an Ext JS date field.